# This code is not drawing the die that its supposed too..any tips? (Java, see both classes)

Tags: java, eclipse

*This code is supposed to create a die based on the the input gathered from the user, on how many dots on the face of the die, and the dies location.*

*This is the main class*
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RollTheDie
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 350;
        final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 300;

        System.out.println("Hi! Let's play dice!\n");

        Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.print("Enter the number on the face of the die:");
        int num = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the location of the die:");
        int x = kb.nextInt();
        int y = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("I hope you had fun! Bye!");

        JFrame dieWindow = new JFrame();
        dieWindow.setBackground(Color.gray);
        dieWindow.setSize(WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH);
        dieWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        dieWindow.setTitle("Roll the Die");

        Die newDie = new Die(num,x,y);
        dieWindow.add(newDie);
        dieWindow.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

---

*This is the die class*
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

```
public class Die extends JPanel
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int xCoordinate;
    int yCoordinate;
    int num;


    Graphics pen, pane;

    private static final int DIE_LENGTH = 60;        //Set's the size
    private static final int DIE_WIDTH = 60;        //of the die
    private static final int DIE_HEIGHT = 60;
    private static final int DOT_LENGTH = 10;
    private static final int DOT_WIDTH = 10;
    private static final Color LINE_COLOR = Color.black;
    private static final Color DIE_COLOR = Color.white;
    private static final Color DOT_COLOR = Color.black;
    private static final int DIE_VERT = 10;
    private static final int DIE_HORI = 10;


    public Die(int dieNum, int x, int y)
    {
        xCoordinate = x;
        yCoordinate = y;

        num = dieNum;
    }

    public void paintDie(Graphics pen)
    {

        //Creates the square
        pen.drawRect(getX(), getY(), DIE_WIDTH, DIE_HEIGHT);
        pen.setColor(LINE_COLOR);
        pen.fillRect(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, DIE_LENGTH, DIE_WIDTH);
        if (num <= 0)
            drawBlank();
        else if (num == 1)
            drawOne();
        else if (num == 2)
            drawTwo();
        else if (num == 3)
            drawThree();
        else if (num == 4)
            drawFour();
        else if (num == 5)
            drawFive();
        else if (num == 6)
            drawSix();



    }

    private void drawBlank ()
    {
        pane.setColor(DIE_COLOR);
        pane.fillRect(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, DIE_LENGTH, DIE_WIDTH);

    }

    private void drawDot (int x, int y)
    {
        pane.setColor(DOT_COLOR);
        pane.fillOval(x, y, DOT_LENGTH, DOT_WIDTH);

    }
    private void drawOne ()
    {

        drawBlank();
        drawDot(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);

    }
    private void drawTwo ()
    {
        drawBlank();
        pane.fillOval((xCoordinate - DIE_HORI), (yCoordinate + DIE_VERT), DOT_LENGTH, DOT_WIDTH);
        pane.fillOval((xCoordinate + DIE_HORI), (yCoordinate - DIE_VERT), DOT_LENGTH, DOT_WIDTH);

    }
    private void drawThree ()
    {
        drawBlank();
        drawOne();
        drawTwo();

    }

    private void drawFour ()
    {
        drawBlank();
        drawDot((xCoordinate - DIE_HORI),(yCoordinate + DIE_VERT));
        drawDot((xCoordinate + DIE_HORI),(yCoordinate + DIE_VERT));
        drawDot((xCoordinate - DIE_HORI),(yCoordinate - DIE_VERT));
        drawDot((xCoordinate + DIE_HORI),(yCoordinate - DIE_VERT));

    }

    private void drawFive ()
    {
        drawBlank();
        drawFour();
        drawOne();


    }

    private void drawSix()
    {
        drawBlank();
        drawFour();
        drawDot((xCoordinate - DIE_HORI), yCoordinate);
        drawDot((xCoordinate + DIE_HORI) , yCoordinate);

    }

}
```

Comment: You've told us your goal, you've posted code, but you've not really explained the problem at all. What happens instead?

Comment: Some of the import statements didnt come up in the code but i assure you I have all of them in so thats not the problem I think.

Comment: You should ***describe*** your problem.

Comment: instead of drawing what its supposed to i get an empty window with nothing in it.

Answer (score 1):

Your class has a `paintDie(Graphics g)` method which contains the code for drawing things, but it is never called, so it makes sense that nothing is seen. In addition, your JPanel class does not have a `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method override which is where drawing ***should*** be done. Without this, nothing will be drawn.

Try changing paintDie to paintComponent:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics pen) {
   super. paintComponent(pen);
   // ... etc
}
```

Don't forget to add the `@Override` annotation so that you know that you are in fact overriding a parent method.

Comment: Doing this gives me the following error:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @user3457911: then find the line that throws the exception and fix it. Find out which variable is null on that line, look back in your code and make sure it is initialized.